# Propagation of linker dependencies in a library

Tags: c++, linux, linker, libraries

If I create static library that has to be linked against some libraries in my system (*.so), when I later want to use an executable that links against the created library, do I also have to explicitly link the executable with said system libraries?

Comment: That shared object will need to exist on the path when the executable is run.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? I'm relatively new to this whole libraries stuff.

Comment: By explicitly I mean passing `-lGl` `-lSOIL` flags to the compiler when building the executable when I already passed those when creating the library.

Comment: Yes, I think you have to, otherwise, how will the linker know that the undefined symbols in the library will be resolved.